# How to replace occured strings with a counter in Go regexp?

Tags: regex, go

For example, in this sentence,

```
Let freedom ring from the mighty mountains of New York. Let freedom ring from the heightening Alleghenies of Pennsylvania. Let freedom ring from the snow-capped Rockies of Colorado. Let freedom ring from the curvaceous slopes of California.
```

how to replace "**Let freedom**" with

"[1] Let freedom", 
"[2] Let freedom2", and so on.

I searched the Go regexp package, failed to find anything related increase counter. (Only find the `ReplaceAllStringFunc`, but I don't know how to use it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to somehow share counter between successive calls to your function. One way to do this is to construct closure. You can do it this way:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := "Let freedom ring from the mighty mountains of New York. Let freedom ring from the heightening Alleghenies of Pennsylvania. Let freedom ring from the snow-capped Rockies of Colorado. Let freedom ring from the curvaceous slopes of California."
    counter := 1
    repl := func(match string) string {
        old := counter
        counter++
        if old != 1 {
            return fmt.Sprintf("[%d] %s%d", old, match, old)
        }
        return fmt.Sprintf("[%d] %s", old, match)
    }
    re := regexp.MustCompile("Let freedom")
    str2 := re.ReplaceAllStringFunc(str, repl)
    fmt.Println(str2)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! +1 for your explanation on construct closure. Your code works well. I don't understand the  `if old != 1 {
            return fmt.Sprintf("[%d] %s%d", old, match, old)
        }` part. So I removed it, the code still works.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this

```
r, i := regexp.MustCompile("Let freedom"), 0
r.ReplaceAllStringFunc(input, func(m string) string {
   i += 1
   if i == 1 {
     return "[1]" + m 
   }
   return fmt.Sprintf("[%d] %s%d", i, m, i)
})
```

Make sure you've imported required packages.. The above works by using `Let freedom` as the regex and then using some conditions to return what is intended.